Completely deleting elements from Matlab R2020b cell array
I have a Matlab R2020b cell array with <missing> values:
my_array =

  6×1 cell array

    {'a'        }
    {'b'        }
    {'c'        }
    {'d'        }
    {1×1 missing}
    {1×1 missing}

I want to delete all the <missing> values from the array, so I created a function called cleanup():
function array = cleanup(array)
    for i = 1:length(array)
       if ismissing(array{i})
           array{i}=[];
       end
    end
end

This function replaces <missing> values with an empty array [], like the Mathworks cell array documentation describes. However, the output is
my_array =

  6×1 cell array

    {'a'        }
    {'b'        }
    {'c'        }
    {'d'        }
    {0×0 double }
    {0×0 double }

What I really want is to completely eliminate the missing values, resulting in a 4x1 cell array. How do I accomplish that?

You probably want array(i)=[]; instead of array{i}=[], to delete the cell rather than the cell's contents. You might also want to change for i = 1:length(array) to for i = length(array):-1:1 to delete from last to first, and thus avoid changing the indices of parts of the array that haven't been processed yet

The answer I gave you in your other question does this. You don’t need to loop. You can’t loop and erase elements in the loop, that is really hard to get working correctly.
